# How to handle LogonHours property on Windows 10 with Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi, user-profile, get-wmiobject

I'm stucked with an issue to read logonHours Property, would appreciate any help.

On a server or any computer that I have RSAT.ActiveDirectory installed I can read with `Get-ADUser -Identity 'user' -Property LogonHours`, manipulate to and from the bits/bytes format to a more human friendly way.

But I need to read it from any/all workstation in a network where mostly don't have RSAT installed and I think installing it on every machine doesn't make sense.

Googling, I found a WMI way to get the property like this `Get-WMIObject -Class 'Win32_NetworkLoginProfile' -Property LogonHours -Filter "Caption Like '$Env:UserName'"`

I was expecting to get the value in a similar format as bytes array with 168 bit representing the hours of a week as documented here ([Docs.MS.CIM_Win32_NetworkLoginProfile#LogonHours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkloginprofile#LogonHours)). But instead, I'm getting something like bellow, which is impossible to manipulate due to issues with timezone diferences and the messy result, for instance, the first hour for monday actually is something like 1900 on sunday:

```
# net user username /time:w-su,8-18
# Get-WMIObject -Class 'Win32_NetworkLoginProfile' -Property LogonHours -Filter "Caption Like '$Env:UserName'"
-- Sunday: 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200,
-- Monday: Access Denied
-- Tuesday: Access Denied
-- Wednesday: 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200,
-- Thursday: 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200,
-- Friday: 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200,
-- Saturday: 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200
```

```
# not used, just to show the issue
# net user username /time:m,0-1
# Get-WMIObject -Class 'Win32_NetworkLoginProfile' -Property LogonHours -Filter "Caption Like '$Env:UserName'"
-- Sunday: 1900,
-- Monday: Access Denied
-- Tuesday: Access Denied
-- Wednesday: Access Denied
-- Thursday: Access Denied
-- Friday: Access Denied
-- Saturday: Access Denied
```

I'm not a developer and by now I'm using Powershell as it is more convenient for our team, but I think we will be able to handle some simple c# vb.net code for a very specific need, yet, I tried to find something about it on any language and didn't find anything.

Thanks to anyone that could help in advance.

Rich

Comment: I don't quite see why you need to be able to read and update this from any and all WS/servers. Care to elaborate?

Comment: I don't need to update, just read. We are implementing controls to allow users to only have access during their workshift and we wanna to send messages 1 hour prior the autologoff time lock their workstation to allow the user save things and prioritize or request for extra hours to their manager. and we have to enforce it due to union rules/agreement with companies.

Comment: I see, you said `which is impossible to manipulate` so I took that as update. Anyway, can't all this be done with GPO? I coulda sworn there was a way to notify the user before forced logg off, or is the notification simply not good enough?

Comment: We have enable the notification, but it is only for 1 minute prior autologoff. our HR are the bosses on this project and they requested to have in most cases 2 hours notification and then 15 min notification. What I created as PoC was use Get-ADUser -Property LogonHours, get the time for logoff, get current time, check the diference and if it is 2 hours, I send a notification. It runs in a schedule every minute as there are many work shifts and could be added extra hours too... the current way works, but needs RSAT on every machine as I run the schedule on the machine. Will try [ADSI] now

Comment: I never used [ADSI], so, have no clue how to get the values. If anyone could give some sample code to get LogonHours for a specific user, I would appreciate

Comment: You should be able to fetch the property using DirectorySearcher.

Comment: @notjustme, thanks for pointing to the DirectorySearcher. It was what I needed.